# Not able to query records from Hive , when data stored as AVRO format , returns "error_error..." exception

Tags: hive, sqoop, avro

We have followed the below steps ,

1. imported a table from MySQL to HDFS location `user/hive/warehouse/orders/`, the table schema as

   ```
   mysql> describe orders;
   +-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | order_id          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | order_date        | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | order_customer_id | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | order_items       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   +-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   ```
2. Created an External Table in Hive using the same data from (1).

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE orders
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
   STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
   OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
   LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db/orders'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://host_name//tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/bb8e849c53ab9ceb0ddec7441115125d/orders.avsc');
   ```

   Sqoop Command :

   ```
    sqoop import \
     --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
     --username=root \
     --password=cloudera \
     --table orders \
     --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/retail_stage.db/orders \
     --as-avrodatafile \
     --split-by order_id
   ```
3. Describe formatted orders , returning error , tried many combination but failed.

   ```
   hive> describe orders;
   OK
   error_error_error_error_error_error_error   string                  from deserializer   
   cannot_determine_schema string                  from deserializer   
   check                   string                  from deserializer   
   schema                  string                  from deserializer   
   url                     string                  from deserializer   
   and                     string                  from deserializer   
   literal                 string                  from deserializer   
   Time taken: 1.15 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
   ```

Same thing worked for `--as-textfile` , where as throwing error in case of `--as-avrodatafile`.

Referred some stack overflow but did not able to resolve. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reference to avro schema file in TBLPROPERTIES should be checked.

does following resolve?

hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://host_name//tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/bb8e849c53ab9ceb0ddec7441115125d/orders.avsc

I was able to create exact scenario and select from hive table.

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sqoop_test
    > COMMENT "A table backed by Avro data with the Avro schema stored in HDFS"
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'    
    > STORED AS 
    >    INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'    
>    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
> LOCATION '/user/cloudera/categories/'    
> TBLPROPERTIES 
>  ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///user/cloudera/categories.avsc')
> ;
```

OK
Time taken: 1.471 seconds

```
 hive> select * from sqoop_test;
 OK
 1  2   Football
 2  2   Soccer
 3  2   Baseball & Softball
```